# Why would it be better to use an authorization library as opposed to my example?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization

I am working on adding authorizations to an app I am building and I have a question.  I have added an :admin column to my User table and set it as a boolean.  In my controller I have added this code:

```
class ShipsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    ships = Ship.all
    @ships = ships.sort_by { |v| [v[:empire_image], v[:cost]] }
    if current_user.admin == true
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # index.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @ships }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
      end
    end
  end
```

It looks like I will have to add this to all of my actions and this seems wrong.  My question is, is doing it this way insecure or just more work for myself but fine.

Also I am using the authentication from railstutorial.org and am wondering if a library like cancan would work well with that.

Thanks for your time,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way is not insecure, it's just *clutter your controllers*, at least consider to use a before_filter to authorize your actions.

Maybe for a simple application use a 3rd party authorization gem could seems overkill but move the **authorization rules in a single place** is a very good thing (the `ability.rb` file in the case of CanCan).

You can use CanCan with that authentication system, CanCan just expects a `current_user` method to exist in the controller.

Comment: Thanks Aldo, appreciate the response.  I ended up going with cancan and it was surprisingly easy to get working.

Comment: You're welcome! A really good point of using CanCan is the documentation, I suggest you to read it if you find some issue. BTW the gem seems to be pretty flexible, probably you'll not use all this power at the start but it could be handy later.